# Trouble making an installer- File not found

Tags: c#, installation, windows-installer, installshield-le

I have made an application and want to distribute it to my friends. I can't do `Clickonce` because, my application needs command line arguments and I have heard that `Clickonce` apps can't accept command line arguments. To make the setup I used the install shield limited edition and made all the required changes to it.  The file which I add to install-shield project assistant is located in the bin\Debug folder of my solution.
The problem which I am facing is that although the installation works fine on my computer, on my friend's computer it doesn't. The error occurs that the installer is unable to find the ".exe" file.
I have been trying to correct this error from past 3 days but of no use. I googled and tried on my own many times , but the problem still is there.

I tried using InnoSetup but the same error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using the `Project Assistant` tab. Are you adding these files to the `Application Files` and mapping where they will be deployed on the Target machine? Otherwise, your installed program will not have all the dependent files necessary to run.

Your view should look like this:

[image: InstallShield Application Files]

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but the problem remains as it is. When I click on the Disk1 folder made in the "setup" project created by installshield, Instead of creating a copy of ".exe" file in the `ProgramFiles` folder, it leaves the folder as empty. How can I correct that

Comment: What's your exact project type? See here: http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/ProjectTypes.htm